# IntelliJ Structural Search : Try Catch in Tests

Tags: java, optimization, intellij-idea, junit, structural-search

I recently switched from Eclipse to IntelliJ Idea, and I'm very pleased with this change.
But, I don't get how to write my own **structural search template**.

I'd like to identify all test methods containing `try ... catch ... finally` blocks in order to remove them.
The replace template is second goal, first I'd like to understand how to find them.

I tried to use existing Idea templates to find all methods annotated with `@Test` with this template slightly modified :

```
class $Class$ {
    @Test
    $ReturnType$ $MethodName$($ParameterType$ $Parameter$);
}
```

I also used a predefined template to find all `try ... catch` blocks, I added the `finally` detection:

```
try {
    $TryStatement$;
} catch($ExceptionType$ $ExceptionDcl$) {
    $CatchStatement$;
} finally{
    $FinallyStatment$;
}
```

But I can't figure out how to go further and mix these two templates in order to find all **test methods** containing `try ... catch ... finally` blocks.

Here are examples of "bad tests" I would like to find with it, and "good tests" which should not match the structural template:

```
public class Tests {

        @Test
        public void badTest() {

            // some code

            try {
                // some code
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // some code
            } finally {
                // some code
            }
            // some code
        }

        @Test
        public void goodTest() throws Exception {
            // some code
        }
    }
```

Do you guys can give me a clue ?

Best regards,

Julien.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first search for all test methods and then for all `try-catch` blocks in the scope `Previous Search Results`. This will give you all `try-catch` blocks inside test methods, which might be close enough to what you need?